# Forwarding website to pdf file on another server using JavaScript

Tags: javascript, html, ajax, xmlhttprequest, httprequest

I'm relative new to html, js etc. Till now I worked on websites in a "contained" environment, I only accessed my own resources or if I did others I'd always have a hardcoded link.

My university offers lecture schedules online using inputs for class and date.
The pdf is always saved in following format ../onxx-yyyy-ww.pdf

I want to create a website that once asks for class, then saves it in a cookie and from then on everytime you visit the website it will forward you to the pdf file with the current schedule.
I found out that this could be achieved with something called AJAX, which I don't know nothing about. This is how far I've come:

js part(excluded getWeek() by Nick Baicoianu):

```js
window.onload = function(){
            checkCookie();
        }

        function checkCookie(){
            if(document.cookie!=''){
                forwarding();
            }
        }

        function forwarding(){
            alert('Forwarding...');
            if (window.XMLHttpRequest){// code for IE7+, Firefox, Chrome, Opera, Safari
                xmlhttp=new XMLHttpRequest();
            }
            else{// code for IE6, IE5
                xmlhttp=new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
            }

            xmlhttp.onreadystatechange=function(){
              if (xmlhttp.readyState==4 && xmlhttp.status==200)
                {
                    alert(xmlhttp.responseText);
                }
              }

            var todayDate = new Date();
            var weekDate = todayDate.getWeek();
            a = document.cookie;
            cookiename = a.substr(0,a.search('='));
            cookiewert = a.substr(a.search('=')+1,a.search(';'));
            if(cookiewert == '')
            {cookiewert = a.substr(a.search('=')+1,a.length);} 
            if(cookiewert<10){
            cookiewert= "0" + cookiewert;
            }

            for (var w=weekDate;w>0;w--){
            xmlhttp.open("GET","http://pollux.dhbw-mosbach.de/cmos_extern_kurs_ext/"+cookiewert+"-"+todayDate.getFullYear()+"-"+w+".pdf",true);
            xmlhttp.send();
            }
        }

        function run(){
            var d = new Date();
            d = new Date(d.getTime() +1000*60*60*24*365*5); // 5 Jahre Cookie

            document.cookie = 'class='+document.getElementById('class').value+'; expires='+d.toGMTString()+';'; 

            forwarding();
        }
```

html:

```html
<body>
    <select id="class">
        <option value="on09">on09</option>
        <option value="on10">on10</option>
        <option value="on11a">on11a</option>
        <option value="on11b">on11b</option>
        <option value="on12">on12</option>
    </select> 
    <button onclick="run()">Weiter</button>
</body>
```

My Forwarding Alert is shown, but then nothing more happens and I'm clueless.
If you have feedback to my code besides my problem, I would gladly accept it.

I'm off to lunch, so it'll take a while for me to respond. Thx for the help!

EDIT:

I got everything working with jQuery till the point where it could retrieve the information if the requested file exists. Nothing happens. Maybe theres an error in my code but in console it doesnt say anything. Also did I find in the jQuery API get()
http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.get/

> Due to browser security restrictions, most "Ajax" requests are subject to the same origin policy; the request can not successfully retrieve data from a different domain, subdomain, or protocol.

Also this is my new forwarding():

```
function forwarding(){
            alert('Forwarding...');

            var todayDate = new Date();
            var weekDate = todayDate.getWeek();

            a = document.cookie;
            cookiename = a.substr(0,a.search('='));
            cookiewert = a.substr(a.search('=')+1,a.search(';'));
            if(cookiewert == '')
            {cookiewert = a.substr(a.search('=')+1,a.length);} 
            alert('http://pollux.dhbw-mosbach.de/cmos_extern_kurs_ext/'+cookiewert+'-'+todayDate.getFullYear()+'-'+singleWeek(weekDate)+'.pdf');

            for (var w=weekDate;w>0;w--){
                $.ajax({
                    type: 'HEAD',
                    url: 'http://pollux.dhbw-mosbach.de/cmos_extern_kurs_ext/'+cookiewert+'-'+todayDate.getFullYear()+'-'+singleWeek(weekDate)+'.pdf',
                    crossDomain: true,

                    success: function () {
                        document.location = "http://pollux.dhbw-mosbach.de/cmos_extern_kurs_ext/"+cookiewert+"-"+todayDate.getFullYear()+"-"+singleWeek(weekDate)+".pdf";
                    },

                    error: function () {
                        alert("Unable to connect to secure checkout.");//TODO: remove when success is working
                        return false;
                    }
                });
            }

            function singleWeek(weekDate){
                if (weekDate<10){
                    weekDate = "0"+weekDate;
                }
            return weekDate;
            }
        }
```

All I want is any method/function to give me feedback if the file exists, in this case status should send me success or error back. I could work with that if it would work...
I don't see my mistake

Comment: I tried using jQuery, but as soon as I put it as src of my script most things stops working even if they were perfectly fine before that. e.g. my run() function throws not defined error when jQuery in src without it, it works.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Seems like this is impossible to achieve with JavaScript due to the same origin policy.

Answer (score 0):

But that's all you do when get the answer: alert!
Is your response an html formated text? You want to redirect user or to show the content on your page?
Basicaly, you most do something with your response. Replace content of a div, for example

```
document.getElementById("mydiv").innerHTML = xmlhttp.responseText
```

or, you may change document's location(for redirect), or create a link to pdf (I am not sure how you „display” the pdf, with browser plugin, as downloadable object, or library auto-generate html from pdf and serve this instead of pdf file?)

Comment: It should redirect the page to the according link so the pdf can be displayed with browser. It's just for some fellow students and myself.